# how to you alter a sqlite db with coolstorage on wp7?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, coolstorage

I'm writing an app for wp7 using coolstorage and sqlite as the database.

The reason I chose sqlite was because it appears to have a good ability to do updates to the schema.

However, in my testing I can run an 'alter table...' command but if I add a column and then try to read that column I get an error that the column doesn't exist.

But if I close the app and run it again, the column is there.

I thought about trying to close my connection, but I don't know how to do that using coolstorage. Is there a way? Would that work?

I'm new to both Coolstorage and SQLite so any help is appreciated.

How can I alter a sqlite schema without closing and re-oppening the app?

[Update: 15 Dec 2011]
We avoided this problem by making sure we ran our schema updates before querying the affected tables, which is probably the right thing to do anyway.

If anyone comes up with a way to do the schema change after running a query against a table, I would still be interested in knowing.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the built in database? It has built in support for upgrading schemas.

Comment: it lookes to me like the built in sql ce db has only limited ability to do schema updates. you can add tables and columns, but you can't drop anything. At least I can't figure out how to drop anything.

Comment: Ah, [you are correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394018(v=VS.92).aspx#BKMK_MigrationMethodologies). `In this release, it is not possible to remove columns or tables from an existing database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite has the ability to add columns to the end of existing tables in-place, however any queries which have already been prepared will not show the changes.  In my experience, if you prepare the query again, it works.  Alternatively, you could close and re-open the database.  Note that other schema changes are not directly supported, and will require you to do the following:

1. Rename the original table
2. Create a new table with the desired changes.
3. Copy the data from the old table to the new one, as applicable.
4. Delete the original table.